# What is the most efficient way to process numerous $_POST from a form into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that I am retrieving data from via post. For this example, there are roughly 15 fields. On another page within this application, there will be over 50, and I am already dreading writing this out in the manner I have been. How can I condense this down?

(Additionally, please ignore the lack of sanitization, I will add that in a little later.)

```
if (($_GET['mode'] == "update") and isset($_GET['id']) and isset($_POST['who'])) {

    $who = $_POST['who'];       
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];
    $phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
    $phone3 = $_POST['phone3'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $checks = $_POST['checks'];

    $statements = array();

    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set firstname='" . $firstname . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set lastname='" . $lastname . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set address='" . $address . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set city='" . $city . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set state='" . $state . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set zip='" . $zip . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set phone1='" . $phone1 . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set phone2='" . $phone2 . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set phone3='" . $phone3 . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set email='" . $email . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set dob='" . $dob . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set ssn='" . $ssn . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set website='" . $website . "' where id=" . $who);
    array_push($statements, "update subcontractors set checks='" . $checks . "' where id=" . $who);

    include "connect.php";
    foreach ($statements as $sql) {
        $db->query($sql);
    } #end forreach
} #endif
```

EDIT: I now have an awesome foreach loop, but it needs PDO sanitization -

```
if (($_GET['mode'] == "update") and isset($_GET['id']) and isset($_POST['who'])) {

    $query = "update subcontractors set";
    $comma = " ";

    $whitelist = array("firstname","lastname","address","city","state","zip","phone1","phone2","phone3","email","dob","ssn","website","checks");

    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if ( !empty($val) && in_array($key, $whitelist)) {
            $query .= $comma . $key . "='" . $val . "'";
            $comma = ", ";
        }
    }
    $query .= " where id=" . $_POST['who'];

    include "connect.php";
    $db->query($query); 
} #endif UPDATE SECTION
```

Comment: Build the query dynamically. Also use prepared statements or escape the data. Don't pass user input direct to a query.

Comment: just use comma seperators. `UPDATE table SET col_1 = '1', col_2 = '2', col_3='3'... where id=" . $who`

Comment: What do you mean by that? How do I prepare it dynamically? Can I do it based on how many $_POST fields are given?

Comment: @Fred-ii- For that method, later on in my application, I will have a line that is like 100000 characters long if I do that for 50 fields?

Comment: Okay, so I also realize that my array method is not the best, I could condense that down into a single line with setting all of the cells in a single command. What about the top half though? Is there any other way to grab $_POST data, other than one at a time? I have to grab them and store them as variables to sanitize them, don't I?

Comment: I'm trying to find a script I used some time ago just for stuff like this, and for the life of me, I can't find it.

Comment: It just seems super inefficient to dedicate like 50 lines to grabbing $_POST variables one at a time to store them into named variables.

Comment: I did find this though http://stackoverflow.com/q/25683760/ but it's mysql_.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that looks perfect though, the foreach with the whitelist bit is exactly what I had imagined would be possible, I just didn't know how to search for it. I can modify it to PDO.

Comment: I'm glad to know there's a silver lining here, *cheers*

Comment: alright moving to PDO is a little tougher than I thought, for the sanitization part. Should I post a new question, or just edit my code? I feel like this second part isn't really the same question.